# Python gensim (TfidfModel): How is the Tf-Idf computed?

Tags: python, gensim, tf-idf

**1. For the below test text,**

```
test=['test test', 'test toy']
```

the tf-idf score [without normalisation (smartirs: 'ntn')] is

```
[['test', 1.17]]  
[['test', 0.58], ['toy', 1.58]]
```

This doesn't seem to tally with what I get via direct computation of

```
tfidf (w, d) = tf x idf  
where idf(term)=log (total number of documents / number of documents containing term)   
tf = number of instances of word in d document / total number of words of d document
```

**Eg**

```
doc 1: 'test test'  
for "test" word  
tf= 1  
idf= log(2/2) = 0  
tf-idf = 0
```

Can someone show me the computation using my above test text?

**2) When I change to cosine normalisation (smartirs:'ntc'), I get**

```
[['test', 1.0]]  
[['test', 0.35], ['toy', 0.94]]
```

Can someone show me the computation too?

Thank you

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora
from gensim import models
import numpy as np
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

test=['test test', 'test toy']
 
texts = [simple_preprocess(doc) for doc in test]
 
mydict= corpora.Dictionary(texts)
mycorpus = [mydict.doc2bow(doc, allow_update=True) for doc in texts]
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(mycorpus, smartirs='ntn')
 
for doc in tfidf[mycorpus]:
    print([[mydict[id], np.around(freq, decimals=2)] for id, freq in doc])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care to know the details of the implementation of the `model.TfidfModel` you can check them directly in the [GitHub repository for gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.py). The particular calculation scheme corresponding to `smartirs='ntn'` is described on the Wikipedia page for [SMART Information Retrieval System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_Information_Retrieval_System) and the exact calculations are different than the ones you use hence the difference in the results.

E.g. the particular discrepancy you are referring to:

```
idf= log(2/2) = 0
```

should actually be log2(N+1/n_k):

```
idf= log(2/1) = 1
```

I suggest that you review both the implementation and the mentioned page so that to ensure your manual checks follow the implementation for the chosen `smartirs` flags.